# Как остановить цикл в android?

Tags: android, android-handler

Привет есть код(talking_phone), он запускает цикл смены изображения, есть ещё ниже код(button_talking_phone) он должен остановить этот цикл и поставить другое изображение, но как мне остановить цикл?

```
talking_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   /// mediaPlayer2.start();
    
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            button_talking_phone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 150);
    
                Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
    
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio1);
                            }
                        }, 150);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio2);
                            }
                        }, 350);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio3);
                            }
                        }, 550);
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio4);
                            }
                        }, 650);
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 750);
                    }
                };
                    handler.postDelayed(r1, 1);
    
                }
    });


       button_talking_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                button_talking_phone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_main1);
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для остановки цикла с нужными изображениями можно использовать метод `removeCallbacks()`, который удаляет все запланированные задачи из очереди для данного `Handler`. Соответственно, чтобы остановить цикл из метода `talking_phone.setOnClickListener()`, можно объявить `Runnable` вне метода, объявить для него переменную `r1` и вызвать метод `handler.removeCallbacks(r1)` в методе `button_talking_phone.setOnClickListener()`, как показано ниже:

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio1);
        }
    }, 150);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio2);
        }
    }, 350);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio3);
        }
    }, 550);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.intercepted_audio4);
        }
    }, 650);
    handler.postDelayed(this, 750);
}};

talking_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    handler.postDelayed(r1, 1);
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button_talking_phone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 150);
}
});
button_talking_phone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(r1);
    button_talking_phone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_main1);
}
});
```

Также стоит обратить внимание на то, что при клике на `button_talking_phone` мы переводим его в состояние `View.GONE`, то есть он становится не видимым, и при следующем клике на `talking_phone` мы не сможем его снова видеть, если не переведем его в состояние `View.VISIBLE`.

Comment: Отпишись как попробуешь, самому интересно